# Getting sum of column using JPA repository

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I want to execute following Query using JPA repository implementation.

Query:`select sum(amount) from transactions where transaction_date_time between '2017-05-04 00:01:07' and '2017-05-04 23:03:07' and id=2;`

For finding I am using something like:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Serializable>{
Transaction findById(Long id);
}
```

So for sum I need something like this:

```
Double sumAmountByTransactionDateTimeBetweenAndMerchantId(Date from, Date to, Long merchantId);
```

I don't want to use @Query. I just want to create method name which will do my job. So, this is not a duplicate. I tried with above function name but it is not doing my job.

Comment: Where is a problem?

Comment: @scary-wombat this is not a duplicate...

Comment: @ByeBye Really, did you have a look at the link from the accepted answer? see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: @ByeBye If you still think so then please let me know why you think so

Comment: It seems that user want to create method name with given sql rather than use native query

Comment: @ByeBye The user can call his method whatever he wants.  If he can do this without use `@Query` then please provide an answer

Comment: I tried to ask where is a problem because question is unclear, maybe better is wait until OP edit his question?

Comment: I don't think aggregation functions like `sum()` are supported by Spring Data JPA's query keywords: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords. So the best alternative is within the duplicates @ScaryWombat mentioned. And to be honest, wanting to do this without `@Query` isn't much of a requirement in my opinion.